# How do I schedule a task to run at periodic intervals?

Tags: java, timer, schedule

I was trying some codes to implement a scheduled task and came up with these codes .

```
import java.util.*;

class Task extends TimerTask {


    int count = 1;

    // run is a abstract method that defines task performed at scheduled time.
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(count+" : Mahendra Singh");
        count++;
    }
}

class TaskScheduling {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Timer timer = new Timer();


       // Schedule to run after every 3 second(3000 millisecond)
       timer.schedule( new Task(), 3000);   
   }
}
```

My output :

```
1  :  Mahendra Singh
```

I expected the compiler to print a series of Mahendra Singh at periodic interval of 3 s but despite waiting for around 15 minutes, I get only one output...How do I solve this out?

Comment: **Quartz scheduler** to help Java application to scheduler a job/task to run at a specified date and time [check full example of that](http://geekonjava.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-scheduling-job-in-java-via.html)

Comment: These classes have been replaced by the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). See the 7th paragraph on the JavaDoc for [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use [`timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                                long delay,
                                long period)
```

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by the specified period.
    In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up." In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

Fixed-rate execution is appropriate for recurring activities that are sensitive to absolute time, such as ringing a chime every hour on the hour, or running scheduled maintenance every day at a particular time. It is also appropriate for recurring activities where the total time to perform a fixed number of executions is important, such as a countdown timer that ticks once every second for ten seconds. Finally, fixed-rate execution is appropriate for scheduling multiple repeating timer tasks that must remain synchronized with respect to one another.

Parameters:

- task - task to be scheduled.
- delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
- period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

Throws:

- IllegalArgumentException - if delay is negative, or delay + System.currentTimeMillis() is negative.
- IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate doesn't address his problem of getting the output only once.

Comment: @JamesA.N.Stauffer, he needs the output repeatedly, not once.

Comment: Yes, but repetition is simply achieved by adding a 3rd argument -- changing the method isn't needed.

Comment: @st0le. consider the following analogy. The asker is saying "The sky is blue" you are saying "No, the grass is green."- Your answer would be ideal if his question was 'what is fixed-rate repeat'.

Comment: What if you want it to be a random rate within certain upper and lower bounds?

Answer (score 89):

## Advantage of `ScheduledExecutorService` over `Timer`

I wish to offer you an alternative to `Timer` using - [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), an implementation of the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface. It has some advantages over the Timer class, according to "Java in Concurrency":

> A `Timer` creates only a single thread for executing timer tasks. If a
>   timer task takes too long to run, the timing accuracy of other
>   `TimerTask` can suffer. If a recurring `TimerTask` is scheduled to run
>   every 10 ms and another Timer-Task takes 40 ms to run, the recurring
>   task either (depending on whether it was scheduled at fixed rate or
>   fixed delay) gets called four times in rapid succession after the
>   long-running task completes, or "misses" four invocations completely.
>   Scheduled thread pools address this limitation by letting you provide
>   multiple threads for executing deferred and periodic tasks.

Another problem with Timer is that it behaves poorly if a `TimerTask` **throws an unchecked exception**. Also, called "thread leakage"

> The Timer thread doesn't catch the exception, so an unchecked
>   exception thrown from a `TimerTask` terminates the timer thread. Timer
>   also doesn't resurrect the thread in this situation; instead, it
>   erroneously assumes the entire Timer was cancelled. In this case,
>   TimerTasks that are already scheduled but not yet executed are never
>   run, and new tasks cannot be scheduled.

And another recommendation if you need to build your own scheduling service, you may still be able to take advantage of the library by using a `DelayQueue`, a `BlockingQueue` implementation that provides the scheduling functionality of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. A `DelayQueue` manages a collection of Delayed objects. A Delayed has a delay time associated with it: `DelayQueue` lets you take an element only if its delay has expired. Objects are returned from a `DelayQueue` ordered by the time associated with their delay.

Comment: Another problem with the timer is that on changing the system clock, it messes with the timer

Answer (score 15):

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,long delay)
```

Schedules the specified task for execution after the specified delay.

you want:

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Schedules the specified task for **repeated fixed-delay** execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.

Answer (score 2):

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Task(), 1000,3000);
```