# How can I adapt my java program to continually run and execute periodically?

Tags: java, sleep, intervals, schedule

I wrote the following section of java which picks up a plaintext file, converts it into an HTML file, and then FTPs the file to a web server.  As the plaintext source file is constantly being updated, I would like this to continually run on a semi-regular basis.  I looked into using the Task Scheduler in Windows XP (yes, I am on a dinosaur machine), but the most frequent option was once a day.  Is there an efficient/somewhat simple way to use a sleep command and only execute every 15 minutes/hour?

I am including my code for context:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class PrintOutConvosFtp2
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

    //Read in the conversation log
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Documents and Settings/Cuckoo/Desktop/Syss-convos.LOG"));
FileWriter output = new FileWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Cuckoo/Desktop/Conversations.html");
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    //remove some unnecessary clutter from the log
 {
 if (!(line.contains("just hung up!!!") || line.contains("just left the Realm.")
        || line.contains("Hurry, I've many esoteric secrets to divulge, and welcome to BaDbOy's realm.")
        || line.contains("For custom MegaMud paths and additional information, check out the website:")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: Discuss new ideas/issues & see the most up to date information on Facebook!")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: http://www.facebook.com/groups/EsotericEdits/")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: MME Dats, Megamud path files and quest walkthroughs are available at my site")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: www.esoteric-edits.fhero.net")
        || line.contains("telepaths: @")
        || line.contains("I'm a bot.  Try telepathing me with @commands.")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: Remember, you can telepath me @commands for useful things like adding lives.")
        || line.contains("Syss gossips: Bring a friend, help keep mud alive!")
        || line.contains("You say \"http://esoteric-edits.fhero.net/\"")
        || line.contains("For a list of available commands, you can telepath me with @commands.")))
 {
 //make the dates american style
     String day = line.substring(0,2);
     String month = line.substring(3,5);
lines.add(month + "/" + day + line.substring(5));
}


 }
//initialize the output file with HTML header
output.write("<html>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<head>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t\t<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"stylesheet.css\"/>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t\t<title>Esoteric Edits BBS - Conversation Log</title>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t</head>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<body>"+ System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<div id='cssmenu'>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t\t<center><img src=\"logo_10_2.png\">");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<ul>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li> <a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li> <a href='downloads.html'><span>Downloads</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li> <a href='Quests.html'><span>Quest Walkthroughs</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li> <a href='https://www.facebook.com/groups/EsotericEdits/'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li> <a href='captures.html'><span>Captures</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t<li class='last'> <a href='FAQs.html'><span>FAQs</span></a></li>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "</ul></center>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "</div><div id='mainpage'>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<center><img src=\"divider.png\"></center>");

//write out a new file with HTML coloration
for (ListIterator<String> iter = lines.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
{
    String currentline = iter.next();
    output.write("<b>"); //make everything bold
    if (currentline.contains("gangpaths: "))
{
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<font color=\"#808000\">" + currentline + "<br></font>");
}
    else if (currentline.contains("gossips: ") || currentline.contains("auctions: "))
{
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<font color=\"#FF00FF\">" + currentline + "<br></font>");
}
else if (currentline.contains("Broadcast from "))
{
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<font color=\"yellow\">" + currentline + "<br></font>");
}
else if (currentline.contains("says \"") || currentline.contains("greets you.") || currentline.contains("bows deeply.")
             || currentline.contains("breaks into a wide grin.") || currentline.contains("You say \"") 
             || currentline.contains("nods affirmatively.") || currentline.contains("grin slyly"))
{
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "<font color=\"green\">" + currentline + "<br></font>");
}
else
{
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + currentline + "<br>");
}
}
//finalize the HTML footer
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "</b>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "</div>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "</body>");
output.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\t</html>");
output.close(); //file is finalized locally

//Log file location for FTPs
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Cuckoo/Desktop/Convo-Upload.log", true));

//define variables for FTP process
String server = "servername";
int port = 21;
String user = "fake";
String pass = "password";

//begin FTP process to web server
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {

    File localFile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Cuckoo/Desktop/Conversations.html");
    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    fis = new FileInputStream(localFile);
    String remoteFile = "/public_html/Conversations.html";
    ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFile, fis);
    java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime());
    writer.append("Successfully uploaded file as of " + currentTimestamp.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    ftpClient.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

writer.close(); //close the FTP logger
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I schedule a task to run at periodic intervals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544197/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-to-run-at-periodic-intervals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the program sleep for 15 minutes between executing its logic. That way the program is constantly running (no need for a scheduler to restart it), but it'll sleep while it's not doing its thing. Of course if the program exits/crashes, you'll need to somehow notice and restart it.

Basically wrap it all in a while loop and add a `Thread.sleep(...);` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows XP task scheduler can be set to run more often. You need to go to the `Advanced` tab. See this answer [How to schedule task to run every 10 minutes, from 8:00 to 15:00 on multiple days of week (with schtask.exe)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/366211/how-to-schedule-task-to-run-every-10-minutes-from-800-to-1500-on-multiple-day)

Alternatively, you could use the `Watch Service API`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html for more information. Note that this requires Java 1.7 or later.

"The java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering, you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file creation, file deletion, or file modification. When the service detects an event of interest, it is forwarded to the registered process. The registered process has a thread (or a pool of threads) dedicated to watching for any events it has registered for. When an event comes in, it is handled as needed."