Can't stop java application wrapped as windows service using procrun
I am trying to wrap a java application as a windows service. I use procrun to do so and it works fairly good (I can install the service and start it, the application works fine), but when I try to stop the service it just doesn't and I don't know why. This is the code of the class that my service is calling when I start and when I try to stop the service:
package com;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("start")) {
            startService();
        }
    }
    
    public static void stop(String args[]) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("stop")) {
            stopService();
        }return;
    }
    
    private static void startService() {
        logger.info("Starting service...");
        int delay = 60 - LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
        scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1); 
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                DateTimeFormatter formatter;
                LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0).withSecond(0);
                formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                insertData(date.format(formatter));
            }

        }, delay, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    
    private static void stopService() {
        logger.info("Stopping service...");
        if (scheduler != null) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
            try {
                if (!scheduler.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
                    scheduler.shutdownNow();
                    logger.info("Service correctly stopped.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                scheduler.shutdownNow();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        if (!(scheduler.isShutdown() && scheduler.isTerminated())) {
            logger.error("Service couldn't stop correctly.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }   
    
    private static void insertData(String date) {
        Connection con = getConexion();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO dbTable VALUES ('"+date+"', 123);";
        if(con != null) {
            try {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(sql);
                logger.info("Data successfully inserted.");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                con.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static Connection getConexion() {
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/database";
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Connection with the database was not possible. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }
}

As additional information, when I try to stop the service it doesn't log any information to the log files (none of the log messages in the stop() method appear), the stop call just hangs until a windows error pops up saying that the service took too long to stop. Also, the application keeps being executed until I kill the thread myself using the terminal. Any idea on why the service behaves this way? This is the batch file that I use to install the service:
@echo off
set "SERVICE_PATH=%cd%"
set "SERVICE_NAME=TestService"
set "EXECUTABLE=%SERVICE_PATH%\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
set "INSTALLER=%EXECUTABLE%"
set "LOG_PATH=C:\TestService\logs\serviceLogs"
set "CLASSPATH=%SERVICE_PATH%\TestService.jar"
set "JVM=auto"
set "SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE=manual"
set "JvmMs=512"
set "JvmMx=1024"

"%INSTALLER%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --Description="Test service" ^
    --DisplayName="TestService" ^
    --Install="%EXECUTABLE%" ^
    --LogPath="%LOG_PATH%" ^
    --StdOutput=C:\TestService\stdout.log ^
    --StdError=C:\TestService\stderr.log ^
    --Classpath="%CLASSPATH%" ^
    --Jvm="%JVM%" ^
    --StartMode=java ^
    --StopMode=java ^
    --StartPath="%SERVICE_PATH%" ^
    --StopPath="%SERVICE_PATH%" ^
    --StartClass=com.Main ^
    --StopClass=com.Main ^
    --StartMethod=main ^
    --StopMethod=stop ^
    --StartParams=start ^
    --StopParams=stop ^
    --Startup="%SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE%" ^
    --JvmMs="%JvmMs%" ^
    --JvmMx="%JvmMx%"
    
if not errorlevel 1 goto installed
echo Service '%SERVICE_NAME%' could not be installed
exit /b 1
:installed
echo Service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been installed
exit /b 0

I have tried changing the batch file so that its startmode is jvm (it looks like it behaves the same way) and I have checked that the properties of the registry editor are ok.
Thanks for reading.

Why do you call Thread.currentThread().interrupt()? Why do you expect the current thread that procrun is calling with a stop argument is the same that is executing the other class of your application?

Probably not related to the question but looping for a specific second is a bad pattern. Try with other alternatives like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27159505/721855

@aled I have tried deleting the class Prunssrv because it was kind of redundant to the class MyClass and handled the arguments in this class to make it clearer. The result was the same, I could launch the app as a service but it didn't stop properly. I have also changed the way I get the date and insert the data using the ScheduledExecutorService as you suggested.

You should probably build this up starting with something much simpler. In fact, you would do well to post  a minimal reproducible example of the code you want to run without any of its service paraphernalia. You can get that in afterwards

@g00se I've tried reducing the code to the simplest. I left the service part because I think the code of the application itself is simple. I hope this is easier to read and someone can help.

Yes that's a lot better. The next thing you can do (you needn't post the changes) is do some plain System.out.println shadowing of your proper logging statements. This on the basis of logging being in itself not configured properly and therefore not helping. I'm hoping you will see that in the configured --StdOutput=C:\TestService\stdout.log 

You can simplify and tighten up that db stuff with private static int insertData() throws SQLException {final String SQL = "INSERT INTO dbTable VALUES (?, 123)";try (Connection con = getConexion(); PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL)) {ps.setObject(1, LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0));return ps.executeUpdate();}}
