# How to send data to server each 15 min time interval

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My requirement is I have to send longitude and latitude from Android to PHP server. I am able to get current latitude and and longitude using Service and `LocationListener`. I am also succeeded to send those data to PHP server using `AsyncTask`. But I could not call `AsyncTask` 15 min interval.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I schedule a task to run at periodic intervals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544197/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-to-run-at-periodic-intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do your thing here, such as execute AsyncTask or send data to server
    }
}, 1000, 900000); // starts your code after 1000 milliseconds, then repeat it every 15 minutes (900000 milliseconds)
```