# Executing java program periodically

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable

I'm a rookie in programming and I have only basic concepts of Java. I need for a school project a solution for executing a Java program (class) periodically (let's say once every 6 hours) and collecting the data from it. The Java program is a client that collects messages published by a server once every 5 minutes. For resolving this my first thought was `Thread()` and `Runnable()` but like I said I have only basic concepts of Java and I don't know how to do it. The solution has to be in Java too. If someone has any ideas help is much appreciated, thanks
PS sorry for my bad english...

Comment: You may use a schedulling library such as [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544197/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-to-run-at-periodic-intervals) [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/)

Comment: @dotvav depending on the complexity of his project, quartz may be an overkill. He can first take a look at simpler solutions.

Comment: @Swapnil that comment went out as a pure reflex. Small projects/assignments may use simpler approaches.

Comment: thank you for your help, i will try the solutions and than update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
- Program manually a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)
- Define a [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) (as proposed by [OldCurmudgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823393/oldcurmudgeon))

**QUARTZ CRONTRIGGER**
Check [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) documentation. ([Here you will find contrigger pattern doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger))

executed at `00:00`, `6:00`, `12:00` and `18:00` hours:

```
0 0 0/6/12/18 * * ?
```

executed each 5 minutes

```
0 0/5 * * * ?
```

**TIMER**
Define a thread that checks each x time to launch proces:

```
int SIX_HOURS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6;
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule( new TimerTask() 
{ 
    public void run() { 
    // do your work 
    } 
}, 0, SIX_HOURS);
```

**DELAY QUEUE**
I have no experience with [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html), but you can find [OldCurmudgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823393/oldcurmudgeon) example [placed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206562/why-is-my-delayqueue-not-delaying-and-printing-in-the-wrong-order), also  [Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/) has a [tutorial here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/delayqueue.html), and you can find more examples [here](http://www.concretepage.com/java/example_delayqueue_java) and [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/delayqueue/java-util-concurrent-delayqueue-example/).

Comment: You can also use a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon updatted with more info, you know some other good tutorial or example of `DelayQueue`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I had some trouble with it - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32206562/823393) for a sample `DelayQueue`.

Comment: Hi @Gon as this is your first question, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.