# Why is my DelayQueue not delaying and printing in the wrong order?

Tags: java

I have the following supposedly trivially simple demo of a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html).

```
class DelayedThing implements Delayed {

    private final long waitUntil;
    private final String name;

    public DelayedThing(String name, long wait) {
        this.name = name;
        this.waitUntil = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait;
        System.out.println("DelayedThing(" + name + " wait=" + wait + " until-" + waitUntil);
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        System.out.println(name + " getDelay = " + unit.convert(waitUntil - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        return unit.convert(waitUntil - System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
        long diff = this.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - o.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(name + ".compareTo(" + o + ") = " + diff);
        return Long.signum(diff);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<Delayed> queue = new DelayQueue<>();
    queue.add(new DelayedThing("one second", 1000));
    queue.add(new DelayedThing("two seconds", 2000));
    queue.add(new DelayedThing("half second", 500));
    for (Delayed d : queue) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

but it prints

```
half second
two seconds
one second
```

which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is a subtle one. I am assuming that the `iterator` of a `DelayQueue` will perform a sequence of `take` calls for each element. **Wrong!**

See the [iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html#iterator%28%29) JavaDoc:

> Returns an iterator over all the elements (**both expired and unexpired**) in this queue.

This was quite unexpected.

One correct solution would be the following:

```
    while (queue.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(queue.take());
    }
```

Note that this problem will also happen if you try to stream the queue:

```
    queue.stream().forEach((d) -> {
        System.out.println(d);
    });
```

As the streaming will happen on the `iterator` supplied by `DelayQueue` this will also have unexpected results.

Comment: Only the top of the queue will be the first. +1