# Print current date every 5 sec with in a 30 sec loop

Tags: java

The do while loop will execute for a 30 sec duration.With in that I have to print the current date in every 5 sec... For that I have written a code as below. But it is not working as expected...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    
    long duration = (30 * 1000);
    do {        
        while (true) {          
            try {
                System.out.println(" Date: " + new Date());
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < duration);

}
```

Comment: I don't see a condition to break out of the inner `while (true)` loop

Comment: How do you think the execution of the inner loop should end? Why do you sleep 2 seconds in the inner loop if you want to print something every 5 seconds?

Comment: @divz I don't see what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544197/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-to-run-at-periodic-intervals

Answer (score 2):

Other answers demonstrated doing this using `while` loop and `Timer`; here is how you can do it using `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
private final static int PERIOD = 5;
private final static int TOTAL = 30;

...

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    System.out.println(new LocalDate());
}, PERIOD, PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
executor.schedule(executor::shutdownNow, TOTAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop `while(true)` is causing the trouble for you.

You do not need a do-while loop for this, unless it is a specific requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = (30 * 1000);

    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < duration) {
        System.out.println(" Date: " + new Date());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

For do-while loop, you can just refactor as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = (30 * 1000);

    do {
        System.out.println(" Date: " + new Date());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < duration);
}
```

Comment: My real requirement is in the do while loop i have to get some server response for 30 seconds.....in between that time every 5 sec i have to send some key press...How i can perform this using the above code?

Comment: In that case, ```Thread.sleep();``` could be tricky. You can use ```java.util.Timer``` as suggested by @elliott-frisch or ```java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch``` with ```await()```

Comment: but where i can put the code for getting server response?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `java.util.Timer`; create an anonymous `TimerTask` to display the `Date` 6 times on a five second period and then `cancel()` itself. That could look something like

```
java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count < 6) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
        } else {
            t.cancel();
        }
        count++;
    }
};
t.schedule(task, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
```

Comment: My real requirement is in the do while loop i have to get some server response for 30 seconds.....in between that time every 5 sec i have to send some key press...How i can perform this using the above code?i tried but bit confused where to put the "get server response code"